# Variable on scope doesn't keep the value changed in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which initializes my value as such:

```
$scope.showThing=true;
```

I toggle the value with ng-click like

```
ng-click="showThing=!showThing"
```

which works ok but then if I try using the same value in a function inside the controller it behaves irrational, to say the least.
Something as simple as alerting the value in an interval function only gets the right value the first time it iterates after changing the value, sometimes not even that. 
Since it's something so trivial I wouldn't want to create a factory for this alone, so I hope there's someone who can tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: can you please show your controller's code?

Comment: $scope.showThing=true;
       $scope.displayTr=function(){
        alert($scope.showThing);
      }; 
      $interval(function() {
        //get data from a factory
          .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 200) {
           $scope.info = response.data;
          } else {
           console.log('Error occured' + response.status);
          }

          });
        $scope.displayTr();
      }, 5000);

Comment: btw, it is better to update your original question with formatted code, than to paste code in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not straightforward, can you post the code. Here is hoisting issue.

```
var a = 10;
console.log("value of 'a' before hoisting: "+a);
(function(){ 
 console.log("value of 'a' after hoisting: "+a);
 var a; 
})(); 

Result:
value of 'a' before hoisting: 10
value of 'a' after hoisting: undefined
```

Comment: I think this is not the case. I do not get any undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

This may be, because interval is initiated once, and then only is returning the same value over and over. Try something similar to this, with a getter style function involved:

```
$scope.showThing=true;

var getShowThing = function() {
  return $scope.showThing;
};

$scope.displayTr=function(){ 
  alert(getShowThing()); 
};

$interval(function() { 
  //get data from a factory .then(function(response) { 
    if (response.status === 200) { 
      $scope.info = response.data; 
    } else { 
      console.log('Error occured' + response.status); 
    } 
  }); 
  $scope.displayTr(); 
}, 5000);
```

Hope this helps.